# can't copy the content inside of variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

My function is:

```
objBD.query('select max(ID_U) AS max_id from usuario ', function(err, rows, fields) {
    copia=rows[0].max_id;
});
```

and the value of the variable `copia` is:

> undefined

the varyable copia is global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `copia` variable is only defined within the scope of that closure. Try defining it before you execute that code:

```
var copia;
objBD.query('select max(ID_U) AS max_id from usuario ', function(err, rows, fields) { copia=rows[0].max_id; })
console.log(copia);
```

Comment: copia is 0 therefore console.log(rows[0].max_id); is a number diferent to zero

Comment: my code is var copia; objBD.query('select max(ID_U) AS max_id from usuario ', function(err, rows, fields) {
  copia=rows[0].max_id;
 });
 console.log(copia); and result is "undefined"